# Xampp server MySQL error ? Status of MySQL database - DEACTIVATED

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7, xampp

I Installed Latest XAMPP server when I start its running in local host its running ,

and also i Installed Drupal and MySQL 6.1 ,.

after installing Drupal i can access to `localhost/drupal` and here Entire Database is saved to MySQL 6.1,.

But in XAMPP at the part of MySQL here its I am Getting Error like

```
6:33:47 PM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
6:33:47 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
6:33:48 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

and at status I am Getting this status,.

[image]

how to run this in xampp

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the ibdata1 file in C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
Make sure you exit xampp first and than restart it.

Comment: yes Daan sir, I Deleted that file which is 14mb and i Restarted again it came with a ibdata1 file of 10mb but MySQL is not working,..

Answer (score 0):

if you install a mysql server separate from xampp, which it sounds like you did, then you'll have issues using xampp to manage it. basically, xampp is trying to start the mysql that came bundled with it, but can't because you already have a service running on that port.

this may help you be able to manage your installation from the phpmyadmin panel.

[Using XAMPP- phpmyadmin while Having Separate MYSQL installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108257/using-xampp-phpmyadmin-while-having-separate-mysql-installation)

personally, i use xampp for my application server, and use mysql workbench for managing the database

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

edit: also, even though xampp is telling you mysql is stopped, it probably isn't. if you're in windows, check the task manager's services tab and see if mysql is running there. it probably is, and you just need to reconfigure the admin panel to manage that instance instead of using the one that came with xampp